# JavaScript tabs issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JavaScript tabs working but i'd like to make it so the first tab is displayed/active when the page loads. Currently there is no active tab on page load.

Html

```
    <ul class="tab">
      <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "active" class to do the hiding (hide anything without this class), you could simply add it to the tab you want to be open on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Adds class `active` to the first tab and hides the rest with `display: none` or create a `inactive` class:

```
<div id="London" class="tabcontent active">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent" style="display: none">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent" style="display: none">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use javascript:

```
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
   document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks')[0].click();
 }, false);
```

or jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.tablinks:eq(0)').click();
});
```

When the document is ready or when the document content is loaded you may trigger a click for the first tab.

An alternative way is to add the active class directly to the element into the HTML.

To add/remove a class to an element in javascript you can use:

classList.remove   or `classList.add`

Instead to use the className.

My snippet:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.target.classList.add("active");
}

// javascript solution
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  // document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks')[0].click();
}, false);

// jQuery solution
$(function () {
  $('.tablinks:eq(0)').click();
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tab">
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```